# RxDart check at least 1 field is filled

Tags: validation, flutter, observable, rxdart

I would like to ask is it possible to check at least 1 of the field and enabled the button which I have disabled using **RxDart**?, so the problem is like this, I have 4 `TextField` and 1 `RaisedButton`, so when the UI first run the `RaisedButton` is disabled, then after either one of the `TextField` is filled, then the `RaisedButton` is enabled to clicked, how can I solve this kind of problem

Comment: where is your current code?

Comment: do I have to post the code? it's only the concept, I'm using the bloc pattern with `Observable` of `BehaviourSubject` and there is one button which listening of all of the Observable, the current problem is when I'm using `combineLatest` it's listen to all the `Observable` but I needed only one of them is valid then the `combineLatest` running its function (valid means that the one of the field have value)

Comment: posting the code makes it easier to follow and know exactly where the problem is.